# PG::Error: ERROR: relation does not exist (rails 3.1.3) on development vs production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, pg

I've blown away my database and am now having problems migrating back to a working database.

The error looks the same as other questions already posted, but I can't figure out how to solve it.  What can I change to get my environment back?  How did it get like this?

I've verified the database does indeed exist, but the tables are not being created by the migrations step.

The error looks like:

```
$ RAILS_ENV="development" bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "documents" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"documents"'::regclass
                                        ^
```

Note: I get the same result attempting any of:

```
$ bundle exec spec
$ RAILS_ENV="development" bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ RAILS_ENV="development" bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
$ RAILS_ENV="development" bundle exec rake db:schema:load
```

THEORY ONE:

It may have to do with the way my migrations are written: I have a class Paragraph:

```
class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  validates_presence_of :document, :document_index
  validates_uniqueness_of :document_index, scope: [:document_id]
```

However, originally when developing this I added the model "document" LAST. Should I somehow change the order of the migrations?

THEORY TWO:
When I run any of these with "production" they work fine (except for my tests of course).

Therefore the config error is influenced in some way by the database configuration.

What say you?

Comment: it could be that you have a migration before that one that uses the documents table, try to change order of migration

Comment: To test this, I 
1) copied the migrations into a single, new migration file
2) verified that no ActiveRecord::Migration contained a reference to a table not appearing before it
3) moved all the previously-existing migrations to a directory not in the project
4) removed the schema.rb

I still see the error!

I guess the "document" it is complaining about could be in the models?

Answer (score 0):

Before migrations are run, the whole Rails environment is initialized. So probably there is code executed during initialization process that tries to use the missing relation.

Run the rake task with `--trace` option to track this code down.

Comment: Good idea - but unfortunately that command wasn't very illuminating:

`$ RAILS_ENV="development" bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "documents" does not exist`